# What's the difference between $get and $find in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

I'm a .NET programmer who've just started to learn more about client side scripting, and I was wondering sometimes you use `$get('value')` and `$find('value')` and I've discovered that these are just shortcuts for `document.getElementById('value')` and [`Sys.Application.findComponent('value')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397522(loband).aspx), respectively.

However, I still don't understand: what is the difference between these two functions in JavaScript? What exactly are they looking up/retrieving when invoked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $get and $find are just shortcuts so you don't have to type out the full function.  You could think of them as function pointers or delegates.  There is a lot to learn regarding client-side scripting.  A good place to start for .NET is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398874.aspx  Keep in mind that different browsers do things differently and Microsoft doesn't always support it all.  I'd recommend learning jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page  That's what we use at work for most of our client-side scripting.

Answer (score 39):

`$get` & `$find` are shortcut functions Microsoft has built into their Ajax JavaScript Library.

`$get` is short for the standard JavaScript [`GetElementById` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementByID).  `$find` is short for .Net's [`findComponent()` function](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/clientreference/Sys/ApplicationClass/SysApplicationFindComponentMethod.aspx).  This is not a standard JavaScript function and is specific to Microsoft's Ajax JavaScript library.

Matt Berseth does a great write up of the differences & usages [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100212204840/http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/the_everuseful_get_and_find_as.html).

Answer (score 19):

1. `$get(elementId)` returns a DOM element, same as `document.getElementById(elementId)`
2. `$find(elementId)` returns an ASP.NET-AJAX JavaScript object, with it's own functions and properties.

   Inconveniently, in Microsoft Ajax those objects are always attached to some DOM element as it's attribute and are related to that DOM element in some ways, so that's why you have to pass element ID to retrieve the object data.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it is the only one that actually answers the question.  The OP asked "What is the difference?" not "What are they?"

Answer (score 0):

$get is the shortcut function built by Microsoft into their ASP.net Ajax javascript library. It is short for getElementById method of javascript. It is not standard and is specific only to Microsoft.

It accepts two parameters :

- ID: id of the element. Required Field
- Element: Parent element to start the search. Optional Field