# Telerik list box, long unordered HTML list, jump to value using javascript

Tags: javascript, telerik, html-lists

I have a large unordered list (more than 400 items). The list appears in a scrollable listbox from Telerik (I'm not sure if that matters).

I would like a user to type in a value into a text box. If the value they type into the text box is in the unordered list, I would like to jump down to that item using Javascript. The HTML in the browser like this -

```
<ul class=​"MyList">​
    <li id=​"id1">​
        <span>item 1​</span>​
    </li>​
    <li id=​"id2">​
        <span>item 2​</span>​
    </li>​
    <li id=​"id3">​
        <span>item 3</span>​
    </li>​

...

    <li id=​"id499">​
        <span>item 499</span>​
    </li>​
</ul>​
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for [autocomplete](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radcombobox-features-autocomplete.html) functionality.

> AutoComplete is a feature provided by many browsers, programs and
>   controls. It involves the program predicting a word or phrase that the
>   user wants to type without the user actually typing it in completely.
>   RadComboBox has full autocomplete support - while you type into the
>   input area, the combobox returns the relative match for the currently
>   typed text.

Comment: Thanks Robert, but I'm not sure that will solve my problem. The list is in a scroll box that contains a list of items. I want the user to type in a value into a textbox, and then jump to the item in the listbox. I believe I've read you can't type into a listbox.

Comment: Have a look at the project linked at the bottom of [this page](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/listbox/autocomplete-listbox.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Robert! Do you know how to get $find to work? What exactly is that? jQuery?

Comment: `$get` & `$find` appear to be shortcut functions Microsoft has built into their Ajax JavaScript Library. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726304) and [here](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/the_everuseful_get_and_find_as.html).

Comment: Thanks again Robert! $find wasn't working for me because for some reason I had to put "window." in front of it.